# Script does not start excel Macro (Windows 10)

Tags: excel, vbscript, com

I have created a very simple vbs script but unfortunately it does not work. It does not start the Excel Macro. It just opens Excel but does nothing with it. If I then try to open it it says the file is locked by user XYZ.
Any ideas?

```
Dim args, ObjExcel

Set args = wscript.Arguments
Set objExcel = Create Object("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open args(0)
objExcel.Visible = True
Exobj.Application.Visible = True

objExcel.Run "helloworld"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)
objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Have you `(itm As Outlook.MailItem)` on the opening `Sub [Sub_Name]` line?

Comment: Whats `Exobj` meant to be did you mean `objExcel`?, imagine that line will error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the third line:
It's not `Create Object` but `CreateObject`.
Without the space.

Comment: Many thanks Julian, that is correct!! However now it opens Excel but it does not run the Macro?? it also does not close Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Could solve the issue by repairing my Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 0):

Close the Excel file first.

script.vbs

```
Dim args, objExcel
Set args = wscript.Arguments
set objExcel = createobject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.workbooks.Open args(0)
objExcel.visible = True
objExcel.Run "helloworld"
objExcel.Activeworkbook.save
objExcel.Activeworkbook.Close(0)
objExcel.Quit
```

run.bat

```
cscript script.vbs "C:\Test\Book1.xlsm"
```

Book1.xlsm

```
Sub helloworld()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Cells(1, "A").Value = Time()
End Sub
```